# Added Google Analytics Tracking Number to Magento - What now?

Tags: google-analytics

I have added my Google Analytics Tracking ID to the Google API page in Magento. Will doing this alone effectively track all of my sites traffic, or do I need to take further steps?

Google has provided a tracking code which they recommended putting on every webpage. Do I need to do this?

Thanks as always, guys!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to do anything else. The tracking code you enter will automatically be put on every page. Conversion / transaction data is also tracked, just make sure you have ecommerce tracking enabled in your GA account.

Comment: Thank you!Is this the setting you're referring to? http://i.imgur.com/lCsd5D9.png

Comment: And do you feel I should enable Enhanced Ecommerce tracking? (The second option down)

Comment: Enhanced Ecommerce tracking is not integrated in Magento, so there's no use in enabling this in Google Analytics. If you would like to use the enhanced tracking, you should write your own module: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce